# Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create edit page and this error keeps popping up
`Whoops, looks like something went wrong. Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.`
What I've done so far
This is my `Route`

```
Route::get('book/edit/{id}', 'BookController@edit')->name('admin.book.edit');
Route::PATCH('book/edit/{id}', 'BookController@update')->name('admin.book.edit');
```

This is my controller

```
$books = $this->bookModel
        ->join('author', 'author.id', '=', 'book.author_id')
        ->where('book.id', '=', $id)
        ->select('book.*', 'author.name_1 as authorname1')
        ->get();
    return view('backend.book.edit', compact('books', $books));
```

Finally view file have the following in form part

```
{{ Form::model($books, ['route' => ['admin.book.edit', $books->id], 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'role' => 'form', 'method' => 'PATCH']) }}
<!--form content-->
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You have to retrieve one record with `first()` not a collection with `get()`, i.e:

```
$book = $this->bookModel
    ->join('author', 'author.id', '=', 'book.author_id')
    ->where('book.id', '=', $id)
    ->select('book.*', 'author.name_1 as authorname1')
    ->first();
```

Please sobstitute `$books` with `$book` in the rest of the code also.

Answer (score 6):

The error is here:

```
$books->id
```

When you're using `get()` you get a collection and `$books` is a collection. In this case you need to iterate over it to get its properties:

```
@foreach ($books as $book)
    {{ $book->id }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

I too had the similar error where I was using eloquent relationship,
and the problem was I was using `return $this->hasMany(ClassName::class);`
But the relation was of One-to-One so the solution for the problem is `return $this->hasOne(ClassName::class);`.

Here in above sample the first code segment will return array of objects which will be breakdown the flow of eloquent relation in chained eloquent code like `$firstChain->middleChain->requiredData`

Here if `middleChain` has arrayOfObjects it cause above error saying `property doesn't exist`.

Be careful when using eloquent relation to properly mention the type of relation it has

Comment: Thank you Afreed A R, this worked for me, i was returning hasMany in my model instead of hasOne.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code need to update like:

```
$books = $this->bookModel
       ->join('author', 'author.id', '=', 'book.author_id')
       ->where('book.id', '=', $id)
       ->select('book.*', 'author.name_1 as authorname1')
       ->first();
   return view('backend.book.edit', compact('books'));
```

Hope this work for you!

Answer (score 0):

As Mayank mentioned above you get a collection, you neeed to itreate over the FIELDS to get the right field you want.  I am giving the same answer in the sytax which is working for me

```
foreach ($books as $book) {
     $book_id = $book->id
}
```