# Property [id] does not exist on this collection in Form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I designed form to save data in Laravel

and this problem shows me the following error

> Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

This is my Code

**Controller**

```
public function create  ()
    {

        $post = Post::all();


       return view   ("post.create",compact('post'));
    }
```

**view create.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{url()->action ('PostController@store', ['id'=>$post->id])}}" method="POST">

<input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Write Title">
<input type="text" name="body" placeholder="Write Body">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">


</form>
```

I know the problem is here, but I don't know what I can do

```
 'PostController@store', ['id'=>$post->id])}}" method="POST"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Property \[id\] does not exist on this collection instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43320223/property-id-does-not-exist-on-this-collection-instance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the collection

```
 $post = Post::all();
```

Instead, pass one object to the view by using

```
$post = Post::first();
```

or if u want to check particular post or any other condition you can use where clause to it..

```
eg: $post = Post::where('id',$user_id)->first(); // It will return single row...It will solve your problem
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are sending a collection of **Post** models to your view.  The `$post` variable contains a *collection* of **Post** models, which means that the collection will not have an `id` because it is a collection, not a single **Post**.

This:

```
$post = Post::all();
```

returns a *collection*.

Because this is a create method, you may wish to new up a **Post** model:

```
$post = new Post();
```

and add a few things to it and save it before sending to the view to get an `id`, **OR,** probably more useful: you can open the form without form-model binding since you don't actually have a **Post** model created yet -- *just remove the `['id'=>$post->id]` part* since there is no `post` to have an `id` at the time the form is created.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it look cleaner for the route.

**web.php**

```
Route::post('/myform/store', 'PostController@store')->name('post.store');
```

In your view, you can use the route name you just created.

```
<form action="{{ route('post.store', ['id' => $post->id]) }}" method="post">
```

But since you don't have column of 'id' in your `Post` then it returns the error you getting. Try creating a column 'id' first to resolve your problem.

I agree with @Watercayman on using model-binding instead, it's quick and makes the code more readable (and understandable too). Since Laravel quickly matches 'id' with unique id in the database. Take a look  [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding) for route parameters (how you can pass your data through URLs) and how to access your parameter [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#accessing-the-request).

Using model binding will return you a **collection**.

```
public function store(Post $post)
```

Your `$post` variable is a **collection** so if you want to access your 'id' column you will do `$post->id`.